# Jquery, bootstrap not loading

Tags: angularjs

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4vSaJgFEcg&index=3&list=PLFe6qPta9Rb4KftbopyORQymFR0Ud6E9I).

But seems like jquery or angular or boostrap.min.js does not load properly. The file location is correct but still it shows me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

for all the js files I've included in main.html

Here's my main.html

```
<html ng-app='ContactsApp'>
        <head>
            <title> My first Angular Project </title>
            <base href='/'> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/boostrap.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class = 'container'>

                    <div class='page-header'>

                            <h1> Contacts: {{message}}</h1> 
                    </div>
            </div>

<script src = 'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src = 'app/bower_components/bootstrap/js/boostrap.min.js'></script>
<script src = 'app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src= 'public/app.js'></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Here's my app.js

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', [])
.run(function ($rootScope){

    $rootscope.message = "Hello Angular..";
});
```

Here's my server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
//app object is express application 
app 
        .use(express.static('./public'))
        .get('*',function(req,res){
                res.sendfile('public/main.html');
        })
        .listen(3000);
```

Comment: the code looks ok.. are you sure those files were pulled down by bower? do they exist in those directories with js inside?

Comment: how do I make sure that those files were pulled down by bower? Yes they do exist in those directories. The path is surely not wrong.

Comment: Are you getting 404's for those  bower assets?

Comment: One potential source for problems is a typo ` boostrap.min.js `.  I left the typo intentionally since it might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jQuery, bootstrap, angular files in proper folder as linked in your project? Let us assume you don't and let's try that by linking those files online. Then your main.html would look like:

```
<html ng-app="ContactsApp">
        <head>
            <title> My first Angular Project </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css.map">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class = 'container'>

                    <div class='page-header'>

                            <h1 ng-cloak> Contacts: {{message}}</h1> 
                    </div>
            </div>

        <script src= 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src= 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src= 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src= 'public/app.js'></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

And your app.js would look like:

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', [])
.run(function ($rootScope){

    $rootScope.message = "Hello Angular..";
});
```

The problem with you current app.js is that the 'S' of $rootScope.message is not capitalised.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check your paths for the scripts. Based on your express routes, if the js file can't be found it will respond with `public/main.html`. Then the browser would try to load that as a script, which would give the syntax error about `<`